# Alfresco 4.2 Solr 1.4 get transaction info by id

Tags: solr, alfresco

I have an Alfresco 4.2 with Solr 1.4.
There are messages in alfresco.log:

```
02:40:25,212 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  [ru.korusconsulting.dms.server.job.WaitSolrInitJob] Indexing. Id last TX on server: 23684084, Id for last TX in index: 23683878
02:40:25,212 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  [ru.korusconsulting.dms.server.job.WaitSolrInitJob] Waiting SOLR...
02:40:28,498 [JobLockService1] INFO  [ru.korusconsulting.dms.server.job.InitJobs] lock is active
02:40:43,953 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  [ru.korusconsulting.dms.server.job.WaitSolrInitJob] Indexing. Id last TX on server: 23684084, Id for last TX in index: 23683878
02:40:43,953 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  [ru.korusconsulting.dms.server.job.WaitSolrInitJob] Waiting SOLR...
02:40:49,054 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  [ru.korusconsulting.dms.server.job.WaitSolrInitJob] Indexing. Id last TX on server: 23684084, Id for last TX in index: 23683878
02:40:49,054 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  [ru.korusconsulting.dms.server.job.WaitSolrInitJob] Waiting SOLR...
02:40:54,588 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  [ru.korusconsulting.dms.server.job.WaitSolrInitJob] Indexing. Id last TX on server: 23684084, Id for last TX in index: 23683878
```

How can I get info (node id) of transaction by id `23684084`?